# How to manage background processes in CentOS

Tags: centos

I’m using CentOS and can’t figure out how to:

1. Show list of current background processes/jobs (which I run).
2. How to run process in background.
3. How to stop background’s process.

My command that I want to run in background looks like this:

```
activator run
```

So far I found only this command (that runs process in background).

```
nohup activator run &
```

Answer (score 4):

That depends mostly on your shell, presumably `bash(1)`. Most other modern shells offer similar (or even identical) job control facilities.

- To start a command in background, do `command &` or `nohup command &` (if you want to log out and still have it running)
- To stop the running command, `C-z` (ctrl-Z), to put the stopped command in background do `bg`. With `fg` you bring it back into the foreground, `jobs` tells you what is stopped or in background. `kill %k` kills job number `k`, `fg %k` (or plain `%k`) brings it to the foreground. You can start stopped job `k` in the background by `bg %k` (or simply `%k &`).

There is quie a bit more.

Another, quite flexible, way is to use `screen(1)`, check it's manual page. With it you can start a command and disconnect, and connect later from another terminal (or another machine over the 'net).

Answer (score 1):

You approach should work...

Start the job with `nohup activator run &`

Check whats running with `jobs -l`

Stop it with `kill PID` (you can get the PID with `ps -ef | grep activator`)

---

I personally prefer `screen` -- http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

Start the job with `screen -d -m activator run`

Check screen sessions with `screen -ls`

Stop it by accessing screen window with `screen -x` followed by screen session ID